# suggest proper conditional statement to fade tabs with CSS via PHP

Tags: php, css, conditional-statements

I want to change the class of two tabs via PHP, but I am stuck in basic condition. here is my code:

#### CSS

```
.myinfo { background-color:black }
.deactive { background-color : white }
```

#### HTML

```
<li class="myinfo <?=$deact?>">
    <a href="myaccount.php?<?=$qry_str?>" >My Info</a>
</li>
<li class="myinfo <?=$deact?>">
    <a href="myaccount.php?mycontacts&<?=$qry_str?>">My Contacts</a>
</li>
```

What I need is

> if `$_GET['mycontacts']` is active
>   then *My Info* link should have class `deactive`
>   otherwise *My Contacs* link should have class `deactive`

I tried this:

```
if (isset($_GET['mycontacts'])){
    $deact ='deactive';
}
```

But it did not succeed. Please help to write this condition (I think a one line `ternary condition` could work).

Comment: The easiest way would be to get `mycontacts` a value: `mycontacts=1` and then to test against that.

Comment: How is that not working? Have you tried manually injecting your HTML with `deactive` to make sure it works as intended ?

Comment: why you want class deactive in both the cases `then My Info link should have class deactive
otherwise My Contacs link should have class deactive`

Comment: @jimy bcoz by default both have black background, so initially `mycontacts` tab shoud be faded

Comment: @khez yes it is working manually..

Comment: @jimy I can't believe I haven't spotted that.

Comment: @Pekka what will be changes if i do `mycontacts=1` my condition still goes to `if (isset($_GET['mycontacts'])){$deact ='deactive';}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li class="myinfo <?php echo ($_GET['mycontacts'] === 'active' ? 'deactive' : '') ?>">
  <a href="myaccount.php?<?=$qry_str?>" >My Info</a>
</li>
<li class="myinfo <?php echo ($_GET['mycontacts'] !== 'active' ? 'deactive' : '') ?>">
  <a href="myaccount.php?mycontacts&<?=$qry_str?>">My Contacts</a>
</li>
```

By the way I hate php short tags! Personal preference...

Comment: i too hate, but its client request so, after all **CLIENT IS GOD** :-P